# Postgres - Transpose Rows to Columns

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, pivot-table, transpose

I am trying to convert rows to columns in postgres using crosstab or any other ways

Table 1:

| Order_Id | Order_line_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

Table 2:

| Order_Id | Order_line_id | Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | APPLE | 60 |
| 1 | 1001 | APPLE | 90 |
| 1 | 1 | APPLE | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | ORANGE | 32 |
| 1 | 1 | KIWI | 45 |
| 1 | 2 | APPLE | 12 |
| 1 | 2 | ORANGE | 76 |
| 1 | 2 | ORANGE | 98 |

Result:

| Order_Id | Order_line_id | APPLE1 | APPLE2 | ORANGE1 | ORANGE2 | KIWI1 | KIWI2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 60 | 90 | null | null | null | null |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | null | 32 | null | null | 45 |
| 1 | 2 | 12 | null | 76 | 98 | null | null |

Column names are known already but the column values might be duplicate and they should be go next to each other.

i tried hard with cross tab and json (atleast tried to bring in json) couldnt progress. any help pls?

I tried to transpose rows to columns but the columns values may be duplicate. duplicate values must still be in separate column. I tried to achieve in crosstab but it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem cannot be resolved with `crosstab` because the list of the columns in the result must be dynamically calculated against the rows of the `Table 2` which may be updated at any time.

A solution exists to solve your problem. It consists of :

1. creating a `composite type` dynamically with the list of expected
   column labels according to the `Table 2` status within a `plpgsql`
   procedure
2. calling the procedure before executing the query
3. building the query by grouping the Table 2 rows by `Order_id` and `Order_line_id` so that to aggregate these rows into the taget row structure
4. converting the target rows into `json` objects and displaying these `json` objects in the final status by using the `json_populate_record` function and the `composite type`

**Step 1 :**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE composite_type() LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
  column_list text ;
BEGIN
SELECT string_agg(m.name || ' text', ', ')
  INTO column_list
  FROM
     ( SELECT Type || generate_series(1, max(count)) AS name
         FROM
            ( SELECT lower(Type) AS type, count(*)
                FROM table_2
               GROUP BY Order_Id, Order_line_id, Type
            ) AS s
        GROUP BY Type
     ) AS m ;

DROP type IF EXISTS composite_type ;
EXECUTE 'CREATE type composite_type AS (' || column_list || ')';
END ; $$
```

**Step 2 :**

```
CALL composite_type() ;
```

**Step 3,4 :**

```
SELECT t.Order_Id, t.Order_line_id
     , (json_populate_record(null :: composite_type, json_object_agg(t.label, t.Amount))).*
  FROM 
     ( SELECT Order_Id, Order_line_id
            , lower(Type) || (row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Order_Id, Order_line_id, Type)) :: text AS label
            , Amount
         FROM table_2
     ) AS t
 GROUP BY t.Order_Id, t.Order_line_id ;
```

**The final result is :**

| order_id | order_line_id | kiwi1 | orange1 | orange2 | apple1 | apple2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 45 | 32 | null | 0 | null |
| 1 | 2 | null | 98 | 76 | 12 | null |
| 1 | 1001 | null | null | null | 60 | 90 |

see the full test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ELuWIo4U)

Comment: thank you very much!! You really nailed it and solved my biggest issue!! I appreciate it!!

Comment: how can i extend this for more columns like 'Amount'. Say there is new column 'Availability' , is it possible to write APPLE1_Amount, APPLE1_Availability, APPLE2_Amount, APPLE2_Availability?

Comment: I am thinking to create new type  and use in json_populate_record

Comment: sure you can extend by enriching the composite type on one side and the query on the other side with both sides consistent together.