# Postgres turn join rows into columns

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have this database schema:

```sql
drop table if exists demo_contact cascade;
create table demo_contact (id serial primary key);
insert into demo_contact values (1);
insert into demo_contact values (2);
insert into demo_contact values (3);

drop table if exists demo_contact_custom_field cascade;
create table demo_contact_custom_field (custom_field_id text, contact_id numeric, value text);
insert into demo_contact_custom_field values ('7759512f-662f-4139-94fb-8b708c5d11eb', 1, '3232');
insert into demo_contact_custom_field values ('a96993bf-eb38-446c-a5a7-416485e8b933', 1, 'true');
insert into demo_contact_custom_field values ('a96993bf-eb38-446c-a5a7-416485e8b933', 2, 'true');
```

How can I produce this sort of output?

| contact_id | 7759512f-662f-4139-94fb-8b708c5d11eb | a96993bf-eb38-446c-a5a7-416485e8b933 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3232 | true |
| 2 |  | true |

I searched around for various queries relating to transposing a table, pivot tables in Postgres, this literal question title "turn postgres join rows into columns" but I haven't found a solution:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/246508/sql-join-to-put-rows-into-columns
  This seems to have an incorrect answer
- [Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into one, group by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column)
  This is the second Google hit but not what I need (I don't need an array column, I need a column for each joined table row)
- https://dirask.com/posts/PostgreSQL-concatenate-multiple-rows-into-one-field-DLok61 Again not what I need, I don't want to join multiple values into a single cell
- https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-combine-multiple-rows-into-multiple-columns-with-PostgreSQL-SQL-PostgreSQL-development Recommends looking up Postgres pivot table and crosstab but from the look I had on that, this seems to be related to aggregating values to cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically done using filtered aggregation:

```
select contact_id, 
        max(value) filter (where custom_field_id = 'a96993bf-eb38-446c-a5a7-416485e8b933') as "a96993bf-eb38-446c-a5a7-416485e8b933",
        max(value) filter (where custom_field_id = '7759512f-662f-4139-94fb-8b708c5d11eb') as "7759512f-662f-4139-94fb-8b708c5d11eb"
from demo_contact_custom_field 
group by contact_id
order by contact_id;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/nq7s7iUx)

A fundamental restriction of the SQL language is that, the number, names and data types of all columns of a query must be known to the database before it retrieves the result of the query. You can not have a query that returns 2 columns today and 42 tomorrow without any change to the query itself.

---

A workaround is to aggregate into JSON values as shown in histocrat's answer. Or create a view with all possible columns based on the data. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66743282/) for an example

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do this exact thing with PostgreSQL. Columns are assumed to be static per query, so they can't be built dynamically (as far as I know). You can do something very similar, though:

```sql
SELECT contact_id, json_object_agg(custom_field_id,value)
FROM demo_contact_custom_field 
GROUP BY contact_id;
```

That will get you output that looks like

| contact_id | json_object_agg |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"7759512f-662f-4139-94fb-8b708c5d11eb":"3232","a96993bf-eb38-446c-a5a7-416485e8b933":"true"} |
| 2 | {"a96993bf-eb38-446c-a5a7-416485e8b933":"true"} |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/6738)

You could also take [the approach described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74353199/postgres-transpose-rows-to-columns) of programmatically building a return type or query based on the rows of the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider crosstab function
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html#id-1.11.7.52.5

further this would help - demonstration of crosstab:
https://learnsql.com/blog/creating-pivot-tables-in-postgresql-using-the-crosstab-function/

below is not your answer, but it is basic implementation

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
       'select custom_field_id, contact_id, value from demo_contact_custom_field a inner join demo_contact b on a.contact_id=b.id'
   ) t (col text, r1 text,r2 text);
```

[image]

Comment: I have looked at Crosstab related answers before posting this question and I've come away thinking it doesn't have a solution to this problem. Do you have an example where it would produce the result schema like in my question?